# Why does a frame not have an evenly distributed grid to the interface

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I want to navigate through different pages(frames) on my TKinter interface using buttons. First I need a grid that is evenly distributed over the interface so that I can place widgets accordingly on the frame.

To do this I wrote the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Create interface.
        self.geometry("600x300")
        self.title('login')
        self.resizable(0,0)

        # Create 5x5 grid for the interface.
        for cel in range(5):
            self.columnconfigure(cel, weight=1)
            self.rowconfigure(cel, weight=1)
        
        # Create a homepage frame.
        self.HomeFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.HomeFrame.grid(column=0, row = 0, sticky='nswe')
        
        # Create 5x5 grid for the homepage frame.
        for cel in range(5):
            self.HomeFrame.columnconfigure(cel, weight=1)
            self.HomeFrame.rowconfigure(cel ,weight=1)
            
        # Create a label for each cel in the 5x5 HomeFrame Grid.
        # Change `self.HomeFrame` with `self` to see the grid of the interface
        for column in range(5):
            for row in range(5):
                self.rowlabel = ttk.Label(self, text=(str(column), str(row)))
                self.rowlabel.grid(column=column, row=row)
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Both grids are generated in the same way, but the result is different. I added numbers in each cel to show the difference.

This is what the grid looks like on my interface.
[image: This is the grid on the interface]

This is what the grid looks like on my frame
[image: This is the grid on the frame]

How do I generate the same grid for a frame?

Edit: Eventually I want to place buttons on the cells '01 - 04'. Then, I want to place a frame for each button on cel '1 0' that stretches out to '4 4' and changes to the corresponding button being clicked.

Comment: Since there is only one frame inside the main window and you have configured `weight=1` for 5 rows and columns, so the frame will not occupy all the space of the main window.  Just configure `weight=1` for the first row and column only of the main window.

Comment: In the loop that generates the 5x5 grid for the interface(mainwindow) I hadded an if function. `if cel == 0: self.columnconfigure(cel, weight=1) self.rowconfigure(cel, weight=1)` This configures the first row and cell of the mainwindow with weight=1 only. But it still isn't working for me. Maybe I've misunderstood your answer

Comment: You don't need the for loop.  Just `self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Any chance you could dumb it down for me and answer the question with a code block?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one frame `self.HomeFrame` in the main window, you just need to set `weight=1` for row 0 and column 0 to allocate all the space in the main window to the frame:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create interface.
        self.geometry("600x300")
        self.title('login')
        self.resizable(0, 0)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create a homepage frame.
        self.HomeFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.HomeFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nswe')

        # Create 5x5 grid for the homepage frame.
        for cel in range(5):
            self.HomeFrame.columnconfigure(cel, weight=1)
            self.HomeFrame.rowconfigure(cel, weight=1)

        # Create a label for each cel in the 5x5 HomeFrame Grid.
        # Change `self.HomeFrame` with `self` to see the grid of the interface
        for column in range(5):
            for row in range(5):
                rowlabel = ttk.Label(self.HomeFrame, text=(str(column), str(row)))
                rowlabel.grid(column=column, row=row)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```